# For Loop from Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, coffeescript

If I have 3 arrays:

```
parent = [
    'first', 
    'second', 
    'third', 
    'fourth', 
]

parentX = [
    'firstX',
    'secondX',
    'thirdX',
    'fourthX',
]

parentY = [
    'firstY',
    'secondY',
    'thirdY',
    'fourthY',
]
```

How would I structure my for loop in coffeescript so that the resulting loop would generate:

```
someThing.first.x = first.firstX
something.first.y = first.firstY
```

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: What exactly is `someThing` supposed to look like? Do you really have a variable called `first` or do you mean that `someThing.first` should be `{ x: parentX[0], y: parentY[0] }`?

Comment: `someThing` is just a variable that holds a group of layers, so I am trying to access the first layer in the group (the layers are named `'first'` `'second'` `'third'` etc) and set its x coordinate, then set its y coordinate. I need to do it in this way based on the framework that I am working within.. Thanks a ton for any ideas! Really appreciate your help so far, and apologies if it was unclear initially.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now Coffeescript, here's the plain Javascript, hopefully you can translate it yourself:

```
for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    // I assume parentX and parenthY are the same length
    for (var j = 0; j < parentX.length; j++) {
        something[parent[i]].x = window[parent[i]][parentX[j]];
        something[parent[i]].y = window[parent[i]][parentY[j]];
    }
}
```

This will only work if `first`, `second`, etc. are global variables, since it uses `window[variableName]` to access them. Javascript doesn't have any way to access local variable names dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want the output to be this:

```
{
  first:  { x: 'firstX',  y: 'firstY'  },
  second: { x: 'secondX', y: 'secondY' },
  third:  { x: 'thirdX',  y: 'thirdY'  },
  fourth: { x: 'fourthX', y: 'fourthY' }
}
```

If so, then you'd build that the same way you'd do it JavaScript: declare an object to hold the results and then iterate over `parent` while pulling things out of all three arrays:

```
obj = { }
for e, i in parent
    obj[e] = { x: parentX[i], y: parentY[i] }
```

CoffeeScript loops always evaluate to arrays so you're stuck with predeclaring the result if you want to use a loop.

Of course, if you want a single statement, you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (which is what you usually end up using if you want "an iteration that returns a non-array object"):

```
obj = parent.reduce(
    (m, e, i) -> m[e] = { x: parentX[i], y: parentY[i] }; m
    { }
)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cr8dpf0h/

Comment: Thanks a ton @mu is too short. I'm not really concerned with the js output as I'm working in a framerwork that's written in coffeescript. Really I just want to have the output say `something.first.x = first.firstX` in coffeescript, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.. Thanks for your ideas I learned a lot from the initial answer. Any additional input appreciated!

Comment: I'm still not sure what the final result should be. You say `something.first.x = first.firstX` but there is no `first` anywhere (except as a string in `parent[0]`) so that example doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short. Sorry if what I was asking was unclear. Yes that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish.. take the value from the string in the array and construct a statement from that value: for each string in the array `parent` construct statements such as `something.parent[0].x = parent[0].firstX` and `something.parent[0].y = parent[0].firstY`. Apologies for being unclear initially.. I really appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: Isn't that what the `for` loop does?